# Looping though a string to expand a specific character Pyhton

Tags: python

```
Productions = {
    "stat_list": [("<stat>", 0.2), ("stat_list", 0.8)],
    "stat": [("<cmpd_stat>", 0.2), ("<stat>", 0.3), ("<if_stat>", 0.3), ("<iter_stat>", 0.4), (" 
           <assgn_stat>", 0.5), ("<decl_stat>", 0.7)],
    "cmpd_stat": [("{ <stat_list> }", 0.5)],
#more code...
    "type": [("int", 0.2), ("double",0.8)],
    "const": [("<digit><digit_seq>",0.7)],
    "digit_seq": [("{empty]", 0.2), ("<digit><digit_seq>", 0.8)],
    "char": [( "[A-Z]", 0.2), ("[a-z]", 0.4),  ("_", 0.7)],
    "digit": [([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 0.5)],

def generateRandom(Productions):
    r5 = random.randint(0, 1)
    for i in Productions:
        if Productions[i] >= r5:
            return Productions.get(i)


def getStatementFromExpansion(prog):
    start = generateRandom(Productions)
    while prog in "<" or ">":
        if start == "<stat_list>":
            return prog.replace(start, Productions.items(start), 1)
        if start == '<stat>':
             return prog.replace(start, Productions.items(start), 1)
        #more similar code...

prog = "int main () { <stat> return 0; }"
print(getStatementFromExpansion(prog))
```

So the purpose of this assignment is to loop though the prog, and every-time it sees a < > it  would expand it, for example, <stat_list> would expand to either  or <stat_list>. 3. it  would continue to do do until there is no more <>, the out out should look like:
int main(){int F0Z = 0262;if (22682 / 525)double S1;else h = U;while (8 - 594873){4=5} return 0;
my error currently is TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

since Productions is a dictionary of lists, you are trying to compare a list to an int. You have to access the particular value at Productions[i] that you are comparing.

Now for example you have this key-value pair:

```py
"type": [("int", 0.2), ("double",0.8)],
```

And you want to access the 0.2 to compare to your r5, you would use:

```py
Productions['type'][0][1]
#list at type - first tuple of the list - second value of the tuple
```

Once you know what value you want to access, you can daisy chain the square bracket since it returns an object with which you can then use square bracket to access some value.

P.S [get()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) is for dictionaries and allows you to 'get' a value for some key and also allows you to get a default value in case the key doesn't exist. [index()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp) on the other hand gives you the index position of the first occurrence of some object in a list.

Comment: How would i do that?? would I use index() or get()?